# How to test if a function in an R package is generic or not

Tags: r, generics, methods, package

I can list all packages containing the 'auc' function:

```
library(sos)
library(dplyr)

auc.search = findFn("auc") 
auc.search %>%
    filter(Function == "auc", Package != "pROC") %>%
    select(Package, Function, Description) %>% head

          Package Function                                                  Description
1         longROC      auc                                                          AUC
2             AUC      auc   Compute the area under the curve of a given performance...
3              PK      auc Estimation of confidence intervals for the area under the...
4 PresenceAbsence      auc                                         Area Under the Curve
5            aucm      auc                                                          AUC
6         precrec      auc                          Retrieve a data frame of AUC scores
```

Now I want to test if the functions in those packages are generic functions or not. How can I do that?

For instance I want something like this:

```
library(AUC)
is.generic(AUC::auc)
FALSE

library(pROC)
is.generic(pROC::auc)
TRUE
```

A bit of background about the reason I am doing this: when I load any of those packages, my `auc` function in a package on the search path is going to be masked by the one from the newly attached package. This is not a problem if the loaded function is a generic (unless the class names clash but that's an other question). However if the function is not a generic, loading the package will be a problem, which I want to detect.

Comment: Well, there is `isGeneric` built in to the `methods` package, but I can't seem to get it to work...

Comment: @Gregor I believe it only works for S4 methods, as everything in the methods package, confusingly. The package is titled "Formal Methods and Classes", that is S4.

Comment: Ah, but an happy autocomplete accident just pointed me to `utils::isS3stdGeneric`, which does seem to be what you're after (or pretty close, at least).

Comment: @Gregor thanks that was useful. I wrote an answer that works but I will happily accept one that doesn't mess with the search space.

Answer (score 1):

The following function basically does the job. It uses `utils::isS3stdGeneric` pointed out by @Gregor to test for S3 generics, and `methods::isGeneric` for S4. The main issue is that it has to mess up with the search space, so most of the function is actually loading the package and ensuring it is correctly removed afterwards with its dependencies.

```
is.function.in.package.generic <- function(pkg, fun) {
    old.search.pos <- search()[2]
    on.exit({
        while (attr(parent.env(.GlobalEnv), "name") != old.search.pos) {
            detach()
        }
    })
    suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(pkg, character.only = TRUE))
    # Does the package actually have a roc function
    t <- try(get(fun), silent=TRUE)
    if (methods::is(t, "try-error")) {
        warning(sprintf("Package %s doesn't seem to contain function %s", pkg, fun))
        return(NA)
    }
    if (isS3stdGeneric(fun)) {
        return(TRUE)
    }
    if (isGeneric(fun)) {
        return(TRUE)
    }
    return(FALSE)
}
```

It seems to work OK:

```
> is.function.in.package.generic("graphics", "plot") #S4
[1] TRUE
> is.function.in.package.generic("analogue", "roc") #S3
[1] TRUE
> is.function.in.package.generic("longROC", "roc") # Not generic
[1] TRUE
> is.function.in.package.generic("aucm", "roc") # No such function
[1] NA
Warning message:
In is.function.in.package.generic("aucm", "roc") :
  Package aucm doesn't seem to contain function roc
```

Comment: If I do `is.function.in.package.generic("dplyr", "filter")` I get `FALSE`. However as far as I know the answer should be `TRUE` https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/16b472fb2afc50a87502c2b4ed803e2f5f82b9d6/R/filter.R#L110

Comment: Unfortunately although filter is a generic method, it is not a "standard" generic as defined by isS3stdGeneric.  I'm not sure how else to check it